# Xamarin bad ItemSource after refreshing

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my constructor of the data store I check the current date, if its Sunday I populate my ItemSource from 12:00 to 18:00, if not then 9:00 to 18:00, but even if its Sunday and I refresh my ListView it populates it from 9:00.

The constructor:

```
 items = new List<Termin>();


        if (TomorrowPage.camefromtomorrow == true)
        {
            thedate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).DayOfWeek.ToString();
        }

       else if (SelectedDateList.camefromdate == true)
        {
            thedate = CalendarPage.selection.DayOfWeek.ToString();
        }

      else  if (ItemsPage.camefromtoday == true)
        {
            thedate = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString();
        }


  if (thedate.Equals("Sunday"))
  { 
     itssunday = true; 
  }
  else
  { 
     itssunday= false;
  }

  if (itssunday)
  {
      for (int i = 12; i <= 18;i++)
      {
           items.Add(new Termin { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Text = "" + i + ":00", Description = "" });        
      }
  } else ...
```

The task for refreshing:

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<Termin>> GetItemsAsync(bool forceRefresh = false)
        {

            return await Task.FromResult(items);
        }
```

Where do I need to put another check what day it is?

The model looks like this:

```
     async Task ExecuteLoadItemsCommand()
    {
        if (IsBusy)
            return;

        IsBusy = true;
        try
        {
            Items.Clear();
            var items = await DataStore.GetItemsAsync(true);
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                Items.Add(item);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }
```

Found the issue,

SOLUTION:

I assigned false to tomorrow after populating the LV, therefore my app thought its the next day.

Comment: How do you get `thedate` variable? Can you provide more code - where it is initialized?

Comment: provided more code to constructor.

Comment: Please run the code with debugger and see if `thedate` is actually "Sunday" and if `itssunday` is set to `true`.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the `if(itssunday)` line and see if the variable is actually `true` or not.

Comment: Thanx, I found the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assigned false to tomorrow after populating the LV, therefore my app thought its the next day.

```
 TomorrowPage.camefromtomorrow = false;
 SelectedDateList.camefromdate = false;

 reservations = await CheckReservations(currentDate);
```

Changed the order, now it works.

Comment: Please mark the solution as answer, so that the question is closed :-)